# How can I redirect a form post to a third party server to an URL without show the posting results in the browser?

Tags: html-post

I have a form that posts the data into a third party ping post system. If the data is accepted by the third party, a valid response is shown in the client side browser. I don't show the response in the client side, instead I want to redirect the client to a thank you page after submission.

Comment: You aren telling us wich server-side technology are you using, by the content of your question we cannot answer...

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure If I understand your question correctly, so I'm going to repeat how I have understood it:
You have html-form that you're to submitting to a 3rd-party server. You'd like to ignore the response sent from that 3rd-party server and instead show your own.

There are two possibilities I'm aware of:

**Use your own server as proxy**

- Instead of submitting your form to the 3rd-party server, submit it to your own server.
- Use a server-side language to forward your request to the 3rd-party server and send your own message back to the browser.

**Use Javascript**

- Add an iframe to your page, give it a name and make it hidden using css (display:none).
- Use a target-attribute in your form to redirect the answer from the 3rd-party server into this hidden frame.
- Use a javascript submit-handler on the form to get a callback, when the form got submitted.
- Show your own response from that callback.

If you have the possibility to use a server-side component, I'd vote for the first option, as it doesn't rely on any browser capabilities or settings.

Regards, Peter